# MYSQL trigger with update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to build a trigger to update a table field by referring to another table, after the same table has been updated. I have tried the following pieces of code but keep getting error #1064 for every attempt. Could someone suggest what is wrong.
quote
attempt 1.

```
BEGIN
UPDATE `incent` a INNER JOIN `inc_prog` b  
SET a.`earned` =
CASE WHEN a.incactualn < b.n1 THEN 0 
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n1 AND b.m1 THEN b.arp1
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n2 AND b.m2 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n3 AND b.m3 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n4 AND b.m4 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n5 AND b.m5 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4+b.arp5
END
```

===end attempt 1

attempt 2

```
BEGIN
UPDATE
    a    
SET
a.earned = 
CASE WHEN a.incactualn < b.n1 THEN '0' 
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n1 AND b.m1 THEN b.arp1
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n2 AND b.m2 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n3 AND b.m3 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n4 AND b.m4 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4
CASE WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n5 AND b.m5 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4+b.arp5

FROM
    incent a
INNER JOIN
    inc_prog b
ON
    a.Incent_name = b.incname && a.period = b.finyear
END
```

======= end attempt 2

UNQUOTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only put the word CASE at the beginning of a CASE expression. Just delete the second and subsequent copies. So your first trigger becomes:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE `incent` a INNER JOIN `inc_prog` b  
    SET a.`earned` =
        CASE WHEN a.incactualn < b.n1 THEN 0 
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n1 AND b.m1 THEN b.arp1
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n2 AND b.m2 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n3 AND b.m3 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n4 AND b.m4 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n5 AND b.m5 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4+b.arp5
        END;
END
```

In your second attempt you are missing the END at the end of the CASE expression, as well as the (SELECT and ) around the subquery:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE a    
    SET a.earned = (SELECT
        CASE WHEN a.incactualn < b.n1 THEN '0' 
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n1 AND b.m1 THEN b.arp1
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n2 AND b.m2 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n3 AND b.m3 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n4 AND b.m4 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4
             WHEN a.incactualn  BETWEEN b.n5 AND b.m5 THEN b.arp1+b.arp2+b.arp3+b.arp4+b.arp5
        END
    FROM incent a
    INNER JOIN inc_prog b ON a.Incent_name = b.incname && a.period = b.finyear);
END
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Can't update table 'incent' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." when this trigger fires, as the same table is being updated. Would you suggest creating a temporary table to overcome this ?

Comment: @V.Rangan are you trying to use this trigger on an UPDATE on table `incent`?

Comment: Yes. I was. By using the trigger you corrected. Then saw the glitch. Worked around the same by updating the field during the first update of the same table. Thanks anyway. You helped me learn a couple.

Comment: @V.Rangan that sounds like what I was going to suggest, setting `NEW.earned` instead of updating `a.earned`. Glad you got it to work.